# How to make Scrollable label in kivy using .kv file

Tags: python-2.7, scrollview, kivy

I am trying to make a scrollable label which has some text so here is my code

Here is my main.py

```html
from kivy.app import App
import socket, sys, threading, os, time


                            
class ExampleApp(App):
                            
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
 ExampleApp().run()
```

Here is my example.kv file

```html
ScrollView:
  Label:
    text:"hello world"*1000
```

I am facing issues with this....some one please post answer for this

Comment: http://inclem.net/2014/07/05/kivy/kivy_label_text/